# iPhone - Multiple TableViews in one View?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

How exactly does one implement two separate "tableviews" on one view like in this image:
[alt text http://www.jamespwright.com/images/public/multitableviews.jpg](http://www.jamespwright.com/images/public/multitableviews.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just simple tableView with groupedStyle, numbers of sections = 2 and number of rows is sections - 5 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

It's very, very likely that that is not two table views, but one table in [grouped style](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UITableViewStyleGrouped), with two sections. Please see the [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451) and the [Human Interface Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/) for more.